# How to use Retrofit and SimpleXML parsing an XML file from a site?

Tags: android, retrofit2, simple-xml-converter

I am working on a project but But I can not parsing tag img and div

```
<description>
            <![CDATA[<img src="http://static2.tinn.ir/thumbnail/pODIyfkKwjD8/IjHVrSYQrID3BxwLPesqahwN7aUXo3OUWw9I9LAZmOHouNcBEEqxznQJRvM5XCiuNonv46CdTExLdGr8qHPrwnjfAV28dvNLEhdGeiojdYyKmGu1G6Uaig,,/84_48_Untitled-1.jpg" /><div>بیمه بیکاری باید همگانی بوده و همه کارگران و کارمندان دولتی وخصوصی را شامل شود و تنها راه تامین منابع آن نیز مشارکت تمام شاغلان در طرح بیمه بیکاری و تامین هزینه‌های آن توسط خود شاغلان است.</div>]]>
        </description>
```

Comment: What convertorFactory You are using?

Comment: retrofit2:converter-simplexml

Comment: Refer this site https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter